# How to use the heal with current layer and below in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I want use the healing tool on a separate, above layer of my picture.

Is there a option to use the healing tool with 'Current & Below' layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you can choose to sample visible layers when using the Healing Tool.

[From Gimp 3.13. Heal](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-heal.html)

> **Sample merged**:
> If you enable this option, healing is not calculated only from the
> values of the active layer, but from all visible layers.

If you want to heal only those 2 layers, you can try turning off layers that you do not want to change.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew